# Pretty URLs without mod_rewrite, without .htaccess

Tags: php, html, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Without a possibility to access .htaccess I find myself in a creative impasse. **There is no mod_rewriting for me.** Nevertheless, I want to be able to do the nice stuff like:

```
http://www.example.com/Blog/2009/12/10/
http://www.example.com/Title_Of_This_Page
```

**What are my alternatives?**

In respond to the answers:

- I'm building with php5
- I don't have access to .htaccess
- `http://www.example.com/index.php/Blog/` is a known technique but I don't prefer it. Is shows the php so to say.
- How would I create extensionless PHP-files? Would this do the trick?
- How much would using the custom 404 technique hurt performance?

Comment: Which web server? Or, are you asking how to get extensionless PHP urls on IIS?

Comment: Extensionless PHP would create the same illusion right? On the other hand, /Blog/2009/12/10 would not work I guess?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've the permissions to set custom error documents for your server you could use this to redirect 404 requests.

E.g. for Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

In the index.php you then can proceed your request by using data from the $_SERVER array.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. I thought about this for 5 minutes and finally came up with the same thing.

Comment: The document returned still has a HTTP 404 status on it, not a 200.  This will cause a lot of problems with web crawlers.

Comment: @chaos: <?php header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); ?>

Comment: You cannot POST (i.e., you can, but the data will be lost) to an error document script.

Comment: @Maciej Łebkowski: that should not be a problem because clients usually do not POST to you themselves (you say when and to which resource).

Comment: If you use switch-case, send a `200 OK` header before the `switch`, send the `404 Not Found` header in the `default:` case and finally wrap the whole router around with `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`. This way the `200` gets sent to all, but the else case sends a `404`, which overwrites the earlier `200`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also have urls like

```
http://domain.com/index.php/Blog/Hello_World
```

out of the box with PHP5. You can then read the URL parameters using

```
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
```

Remember to validate/filter the PATH_INFO and all other request variables before using them in your application.

Comment: I'm aware of this technique. I changed the question asking for a way without this method. It's an alternative nevertheless so you're right. I just don't prefer this one.

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is very old but I didn't see anyone else suggest this possible solution...

You can get very close to what you want just by adding a question mark after the domain part of the URL, ie;

```
http://www.example.com/?Blog/2009/12/10/
http://www.example.com/?Title_Of_This_Page
```

Both of the above HTTP requests will now be handled by the same `PHP` script;

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

and in the `index.php` script, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for the two pages above will be respectively;

`Blog/2009/12/10/`

`Title_Of_This_Page`

so you can handle them however you want.

Comment: I actually just implemented something like this and found that the single question mark served well to call the index.php page without exposing it as the handler.  it's not *as clean* but it still works without having to configure the web server rewrite rules.

Answer (score 3):

A quite simple way is to:

- declare a 404 ErrorDocument (e.g. PHP) in `.htaccess`
- parse the query using `$_SERVER` and see if it corresponds to any result
- if so replace the HTTP status 404 with status 200 using `header()` and include index.php

Comment: The question, again, becomes, how to do that w/o .htaccess. Some webhosts do offer a custom 404 in their configs, though, so this would be possible.

Comment: Right. I don't see any solution without either being able to choose (or edit) your 404 ErrorDocument or use a .htaccess, because you have to set this up at request-hendling level...
Or use the solution you don't like: `index.php/Blog/...`

Answer (score 3):

If you omit a trailing slash, Apache will serve the first file [alphabetically] which matches that name, regardless of the extension, at least on the 2 servers I have access to.

I don't know how you might use this to solve your problem, but it may be useful at some point.

For example if
`http://www.somesite.com/abc.html` and `http://www.somesite.com/abc.php` both exist and `http://www.somesite.com/abc` is requested, `http://www.somesite.com/abc.html` will be served.

Comment: You are refering to the Option `MultiViews`  in apache. This option can have unwanted side effects. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to use custom 404 page. You have no possibility to interpret extensionless files with PHP interpreter without reconfiguring the web server's MIME-types. But you say that you can't edit even .htaccess, so there's no other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a URI class which parses the user-friendly URL you defined.

Answer (score 0):

If the `MultiViews` option is enabled or you can convince whoever holds the keys to enable it, you can make a script called Blog.php that will be passed requests to `example.com/Blog/foo` and get '/foo' in the `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  Edited per.