# Failsafe for when mod_rewrite is disabled

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My framework is entirely dependant on mod_rewrite to be enabled on a server for routing purposes. Within my .htaccess file I check if mod_rewrite.c is enabled and do my rewrite rules within it. However, should mod_rewrite not be turned on, my application essentially would stop working as I do not want to do the http://www.domain.com/index.php/... url setup to ensure all requests still filter through index.php.

Is there a failsafe for me to direct all requests to say a internal 500 or possibly some error page (if I can define it customly that would be great) if mod_rewrite is turned off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty URLs without mod\_rewrite, without .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975262/pretty-urls-without-mod-rewrite-without-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep all your `mod_rewrite` rules in `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block and exceptions in `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>` block:

```
# execute when mod_rewrite is turned on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# execute when mod_rewrite is turned off
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    RedirectMatch ^(?!/error\.php).*$ /error.php
</IfModule>
```